# How to prevent displaying "Quit" when pressing C-g?

Tags: echo-area, quitting, inhibit-message

Looking for a way to silent Emacs. By using [this](https://scripter.co/using-emacs-advice-to-silence-messages-from-functions/#applying-the-silence-advice) technique I can ignore some messages. But it does not work for `C-g` as it use `signal` function internal. How to prevent displaying "Quit" when pressing C-g?

Answer (score 6):

The main job of `C-g` ([`keyboard-quit`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quitting.html#index-keyboard_002dquit)) is to raise the `quit` signal. The message “Quit” comes from the [`error-message` property](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Signaling-Errors.html#index-signal) of the symbol `quit`. You can make this an empty string:

```
(put 'quit 'error-message "")
```

This still emits a message (with a line in `*Messages*`), but this way the line is empty so this clears the mode line but does not write text in it.

I don't know how to completely disable this message. Deleting the `error-message` property doesn't work (there's a fallback to “peculiar error”).

Comment: That's much better now, thanks!